# I cannot use Qt with CLion

Tags: c++, windows-10, qt5, c++14, clion

I try to make a program using Qt in CLion.
After clicking New Project in the starting window of CLion I choose Qt Widgets Executable on the left and add the following Qt CMake prefix path:

> C:\Qt\6.0.3

Then I click on "create" and get the "Open Project Wizard" window. I click on "Manage toolchains..." and add a new toolchain. Next to "Environment:" I write:

> C:\Qt\Tools\mingw810_64

and everything looks fine. Then I click on Ok and again on Ok and after few seconds I get the following message below:

> ```
> CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:21 (find_package):
>   By not providing "FindQt5.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project has
>   asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by "Qt5", but
>   CMake did not find one.
>
>   Could not find a package configuration file provided by "Qt5" with any of
>   the following names:
>
>     Qt5Config.cmake
>     qt5-config.cmake
>
>   Add the installation prefix of "Qt5" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set "Qt5_DIR"
>   to a directory containing one of the above files.  If "Qt5" provides a
>   separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been installed.
> ```

Please, can you help me?
(Qt is installed on my computer)

Comment: Qt 6 is pretty new, and it's possible CLion (and especially the CMake version shipped with it) haven't added support for it quite yet.

Comment: Even with Qt 5 it doesn't work.

Comment: From the first line of the actual error message: "By not providing "FindQt5.cmake" in **CMAKE_MODULE_PATH**..." (emphasis mine). You need to find the location of the CMake configuration files for Qt, and add the location to the environment variable `CMAKE_MODULE_PATH`.

Answer (score 1):

1. Setting Toolchains, treat qt mingw tool path as default
   [image]
2. when you create qt project, please set qt cmake prefix path, such as "D:\Qt\6.1.2\mingw81_64\lib\cmake"

[image]

Answer (score 0):

try previous version of **qt**.

**OR**

try Visual Studio IDE.

Comment: I could use QtCreator but it's not as advanced as CLion. Also with Visual Studio it's a pain to make Qt work